# Applying the exact same editing to two photos in Lightroom

Tags: lightroom, photoshop

I put my camera on my tripod and take multiple photos with different exposure settings so that I can combine them in Photoshop via luminosity masks.

Let's assume I have taken two photos (A & B) with different exposure settings in my lightroom.

This is my work flow:

1. Apply Lens Correction in Lightroom for A & B
2. Apply Transform using my custom guides in Lightroom for A & B
3. Export A & B as layers to Photoshop
4. Apply luminosity masks and merge these two layers to a final image.

Currently, I have trouble applying the exact same guides for step 2 because I have to manually draw these lines myself.

Is there a way to apply the same settings for step 1 and 2 directly to two images?

Comment: Note, I have also tried doing it this way:
 
1. Export A & B as layers to Photoshop
2. Apply luminosity masks and merge these two layers to a final image, C
3. Save C as "C.psd" and then open it in Lightroom
4. Apply Lens Correction to C.psd
 
 
I am unable to find my camera profile in step 4. Maybe because it's a psd file?
 

Also, since it's a psd file a lot of RAW info is lost.

Comment: Sounds like something that may be better suited for Photoshop to me. I don't follow what you mean by "apply transform using my custom guides" or I would likely submit an actual answer.

Comment: Lightroom has added an option to transform images, by allowing you to draw guides along lines you want to be vertical or horizontally transformed (CC version only, not standalone).

Answer (score 2):

If the camera hasn't moved between shots, just use the *Develop Settings | Copy Settings* menu in Lightroom (right click on one image to get the menu).  Pick the settings you want to copy (in your case, the transform stuff).  Then right click on the target picture and choose *Develop Settings | Paste Settings*.

There are about 4 ways of achieving the same thing in Lightroom

1. Have two images selected when you enter the Develop module, and settings will be applied to both, for example
2. Use the copy / paste method above
3. Use the painter tool.
4. Use the sync settings button.

All of those will also apply transforms - but that only works if your two images are identical.